# map to arcadia and suroundings

Tags: the-100

Last episode of "The 100" bothers me greatly.
Is there a map of the internal layout of the place.

We see Kain by the entrance ready to go out in a rover and we see Bellamy in the detention area. How is it possible for Bellamy to get to the main gate before Kain can escape?